# Azure : how can know about Storage blob upload in my ACI

Tags: windows, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-container-instances

I am new to Azure programming.
I have a service running as Azure ACI.
This service process if there is a file available in c:\data\input and writes processed c:\data\output.
I will have file uploaded to blob storage https://sreestorage.blob.core.windows.net/SStorageContainer

Is there a way that I can get notification about File upload?
SO that I can download the file to c:\data\input.

Thanks
Santhi

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way that I can get notification about File upload? SO that I can download the file to c:\data\input.

Follow the steps below to get an `alert` when you upload a file to an `Azure storage container`.

1. Create an `Log Analytics Work Space`, follow the [Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/quick-create-workspace?tabs=azure-portal)
2. Go to `Azure Portal > Select your Storage Account > Diagnostic settings  > Blob > Add diagnostic setting`

[image]

3. Please wait for some time to allow all `Storage account` transaction data to be sent to the `Log Analytics workspace`
4. Go to `Log analytics work space > Logs and run below KQL Query`

```
    StorageBlobLogs
    | where OperationName == "PutBlob"
    | project AccountName, Uri, ServiceType, OperationName,ObjectKey
```

**Output:**

[image]

5. Click `New Alert Rule` and select the measurement according to your requirements.
6. Create an `Action Group`, and if it has already been created, select the same `Action Group` and provide the `Email ID` details in the `Condition` to receive an email

[image]

7. After creating an alert, when you upload a file to the `Storage account`, you will receive an email alert, and the same alert will be reflected in the `Portal`

[image]

An alert for the uploaded file has been received at the registered email, like below.

[image]